# How to get the center and radius of the feature in openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2

I created a control to draw circle and rect to the map:

```
        var supportControls = {
            darwpoint : new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(this.drawLayer, OpenLayers.Handler.Point),
            drawline : new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(this.drawLayer, OpenLayers.Handler.Path),
            drawpolygon : new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(this.drawLayer, OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon),
            drawrect : new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(this.drawLayer, OpenLayers.Handler.RegularPolygon, {
                handlerOptions : {
                    sides : 4,
                    irregular : true
                }
            }),
            drawcircle : new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(this.drawLayer, OpenLayers.Handler.RegularPolygon, {
                handlerOptions : {
                    sides : 40
                }
            })
        };
        for ( var key in supportControls) {
            supportControls[key].handler.stopDown = true;
            supportControls[key].handler.stopUp = true;
            supportControls[key].featureAdd=function(feature){
                handlerFeature(feature);
            }
            map.addControl(supportControls[key]);
        }


        function handlerFeature(fea){
            // how to get the circle center and radius of the feature if it is a circle
        }
```

Now, after the draw end, I have have no idea to differentiate whether the feature is circle or rect, and how to get the center and radius if it is a circle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE 2:**

```
var radius = center.distanceTo(point1);
```

**UPDATE 1:**

if your shape is circle(not elips), your radius should be the same everywhere.

```
var center = vectorLayer.features[i].geometry.getCentroid();
var point1 = vectorLayer.features[i].geometry.components[0].components[1];
var point5 = vectorLayer.features[i].geometry.components[0].components[5];

if(Math.round(center.distanceTo(point1)) == Math.round(center.distanceTo(point5))){
   console.log("the shape is circle")
}else{
   console.log("the shape is not circle")
}
```

---

if you want to get center of circle, you can use getCentroid() method.

```
vectorLayer.features[i].geometry.getCentroid();
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Then how to differentiate whether the feature is circle or rect?

Comment: Oh,I just thought that I can use the `geometry.getVertices(false)` to determine if it is a circle or rect, but how to get the radius?

Comment: i have updated my answer.